# What is this icon on the top right of some YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

It isn't on all videos but it appears on some. No clue what it is.

[image]

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Vq-xHqUo8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the logo of the video's uploader. Uploaders can choose to display their logo near the beginning or end of the video, to make it easier for you to subscribe to their channel.

Comment: Thanks! In the Android YouTube app it remains on the top right for the entire duration of the video. Annoying. And clicking it doesn't do anything other than display the controls you normally get by clicking on video.